# What is the effect of adding an independent summand on translated quantiles?

Tags: probability, quantiles, cumulative-distribution-function

Suppose that $Y,Z$ are independent, continuous, non-negative random variables. Suppose also that for some $0<q<1$, $$\tau=\inf\{t>0:F_Y(t)\geqslant q\}$$ and $$\pi = \inf\{t>0:F_{Y+Z}(t)\geqslant q\},$$ where $F_Y$, $F_{Y+Z}$ are the cdfs of $Y$ and $Y+Z$, respectively. Then we have (by continuity) that $$F_Y(\tau)=F_{Y+Z}(\pi)=q.$$

What effect do we get by translating? That is, what can we say about the order of $F_Y(\tau-x)$ vs. $F_{Y+Z}(\pi-x)$ for $0\leqslant x\leqslant \pi$? Of course, both functions will start at $q$ when $x=0$ and both functions will decrease to $0$. The function $F_Y(\tau-x)$ will reach zero no later than $x=\tau$, and $F_{Y+Z}(\pi-x)$ will reach zero no later than $\pi$. My intuition is that $F_{Y+Z}(\pi-x)\geqslant F_Y(\tau-x)$ for all $0\leqslant x\leqslant \pi$. But I can't seem to rule out the possibility that the functions could cross over each other several times for different values of $x$.

I've tried to work several proofs, to no avail. I've plotted a few exact situations, and run a few simulations for those situations in which I could not be bothered to get the exact cdfs. I haven't seen my intuition violated.

Comment: Let $U_i$ independently have a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ and let $Y=U_1^{-1/3},$ $Z=U_2^{-1/3}.$  Set $q=0.8.$  If I have computed correctly, the functions cross around $0.43.$

Comment: Can you show your calculations? I simulated these and the functions do not cross in the plot.

Comment: I'm very sorry--there was a bug in my code.  I'll post a better counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an accurate plot of the distribution functions of a positive variable $Y$ and its sum with a uniform$(0,1)$ variable $Z.$

[image: Figure 1]

The question proposes shifting one of these graphs until $\tau$ and $\pi$ coincide and investigating their relative positions to the left of that common point.  The next figure has shifted the graph of $F_Y$ to the right.

[image: Figure 2]

As you can see in this example, it is *not* the case that one of the graphs is always above the other at the left (or even the right, for that matter).

---

**How was such an example constructed?**  Observe that we can force the black curve, for $F_Y,$ to be as level as we like at its quantile $\tau$ by making sure it has very small density at $\tau,$ because its density is the derivative of $F_Y.$ In this fashion the black curve *immediately* to the left of this quantile will remain high.  However, since $Z$ is a non-negative variable, $F_{Y+Z}$ reflects a "smeared" version of the distribution of $Y$ *for values smaller than $\tau.$*  By giving $Y$ relatively high density there, we can ensure that the slope of $F_{Y+X}$ at $\pi$ is high.  This causes the red curve in the second figure to drop below the black curve as we move left from $\pi.$

**In this particular example,** the distribution of $Y$ is an equal mixture of a $\Gamma(100,100)$ distribution and a $\Gamma(150, 100)$ distribution (the first parameter is the shape, the second is the inverse scale).  (It has been shifted a bit to the left in the first figure.) This mixture is bimodal with a relatively level, low-density region exactly at the median $q=1/2.$

[image: Figure 3]

---

Here is a simulation to check (in `R`).  Its output is below the code: it plots the two functions defined in the question, showing how they cross.

```R
n <- 1e5
q <- 0.5
#
# Sample Y and Z.
#
k <- rbinom(1, n, q)
y <- c(rgamma(n-k, 100, 100), rgamma(k, 150, 100))
z <- runif(n)
# 
# Construct Y+Z.
#
yz <- y + z
#
# Define the functions in the question.
#
tau <- quantile(y, q)
pi. <- quantile(yz, q)
fY <- function(x) ecdf(y)(tau-x)
fYZ <- function(x) ecdf(yz)(pi.-x)
#
# Plot them together to compare.
#
curve(fY(x), xlim=c(0, max(tau, pi.)), lwd=2)
curve(fYZ(x), add=TRUE, col="Red", lwd=2)
```

[image: Figure 4]